# How do I downgrade packages easily with Yum?

Tags: fedora, rpm, yum

Apparently, Fedora's `yum` has the ability to downgrade. I find this useful because abhorrently they feel they need to break [NetworkManager on a stable upgrade.](https://bugzilla.redhat.com/show_bug.cgi?id=708445) [In multiple ways.](https://bugzilla.redhat.com/show_bug.cgi?id=708624)

How do I downgrade NetworkManager and everything that depends on it? Can I make `yum` work in reverse?

```
[root@x200s NetworkManager]# yum downgrade NetworkManager-0.8.999-2.git20110509.fc15.i686
Loaded plugins: langpacks, presto, refresh-packagekit
Setting up Downgrade Process
Resolving Dependencies
--> Running transaction check
---> Package NetworkManager.i686 1:0.8.999-2.git20110509.fc15 will be a downgrade
--> Processing Dependency: NetworkManager-glib = 1:0.8.999-2.git20110509.fc15 for package: 1:NetworkManager-0.8.999-2.git20110509.fc15.i686
---> Package NetworkManager.i686 1:0.8.999-3.git20110526.fc15 will be erased
--> Finished Dependency Resolution
Error: Package: 1:NetworkManager-gnome-0.8.999-3.git20110526.fc15.i686 (@updates)
           Requires: NetworkManager = 1:0.8.999-3.git20110526.fc15
           Removing: 1:NetworkManager-0.8.999-3.git20110526.fc15.i686 (@updates)
               NetworkManager = 1:0.8.999-3.git20110526.fc15
           Downgraded By: 1:NetworkManager-0.8.999-2.git20110509.fc15.i686 (fedora)
               NetworkManager = 1:0.8.999-2.git20110509.fc15
Error: Package: 1:NetworkManager-0.8.999-2.git20110509.fc15.i686 (fedora)
           Requires: NetworkManager-glib = 1:0.8.999-2.git20110509.fc15
           Installed: 1:NetworkManager-glib-0.8.999-3.git20110526.fc15.i686 (@updates)
               NetworkManager-glib = 1:0.8.999-3.git20110526.fc15
           Available: 1:NetworkManager-glib-0.8.999-2.git20110509.fc15.i686 (fedora)
               NetworkManager-glib = 1:0.8.999-2.git20110509.fc15
 You could try using --skip-broken to work around the problem
 You could try running: rpm -Va --nofiles --nodigest
```

Is there a way to downgrade without doing each package independently?

Answer (score 23, accepted):

You can use:

```
yum downgrade NetworkManager NetworkManager-gnome NetworkManager-glib
```

Comment: Is there a method like `yum downgrade NetworkManager (and all preques unmentioned)`

Answer (score 4):

If you have previously had a working version on the system in question yum history is a goto command. It will list transactions and allow you to roll back to a certain point or undo single actions see more here;

http://docs.fedoraproject.org/en-US/Fedora/14/html/Software_Management_Guide/ch05s16.html

Alternatively if you wish to downgrade something that has multiple version restricted dependencies using the yum-allow-downgrade plugin will sort out the dependency errors you are seeing. It will add a --allow-downgrade option that you can use.

If you are deliberately sticking with an old version I would suggest looking into the version lock package. This will prevent yourself/colleagues/scheduled updates ruining your work.

http://docs.fedoraproject.org/en-US/Fedora/14/html/Software_Management_Guide/ch06s25.html